# Keyboard & textfields layout

Tags: swift3, uikeyboard

I'm posting this to hopefully help people have encountered the same problem as I have, and for answers on one question.

In one UIViewController I have multiple textfields, some located above the keyboard and some will be located beneath the keyboard. At the same time I have a toolbar located above the keyboard to toggle through the UITextFields.

This is what the view looks like:

[image]

To set the right origin of the textfields I have compiled codes from different answer into this code:

**To register for keyboardShow and Hide:**

```
override function viewDidLoad() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}
```

**KeyboardWillShow selector method:**

```
func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
        let keyboard = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.size {
        let keyboardHeight = self.view.frame.height - keyboard.height
        for (_, textField) in textFields.enumerated() {
            let textFieldBottom = textField.frame.origin.y + textField.frame.height
            let dif = textFieldBottom - keyboardHeight
            if textFieldBottom >= keyboardHeight {
                if textField.isFirstResponder {
                    self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
                    self.view.frame.origin.y -= dif
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**KeyboardWillHide selector method:**

```
func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: Notification) {
    view.frame.origin.y = 0
}
```

**My question is now**, when I quickly tap one of the arrows in my toolbar the code will not move the necessary distance, so that the correct UITextField is just  above the keyboard.

Example: First Incorrect Answer is the firstResponder. I tap twice quickly on > arrow. Second Incorrect Answer will be the UITextField just above the keyboard while Third Incorrect Answer will be the firstResponder and not viewable by the user.